# shell script looping in folder structure and excute shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i've the following the folder stucrtre

/var/data/2017/01/$day/files

i want to excute shell script to for loop in the all months  / day and run shell script against  all files

```
DIR_PROC = /var/data/2017/01/$day/$file
for day  in  {1..30}   do
        echo "processing file  $file
        sh  /opt/myscript.sh   /var/data/2017/1/$day/$file

    done
```

i'm not sure about the logic here i missed the file listing how i can get it

any advise here

Comment: What do you mean "missed the file listing", what is not working exactly?

Comment: I mean when i'm looping in each day ill have multiple files there to run the shell script aginst each file , how i can add the files into loop once done from day 1 i move to day 2 and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dir_proc=/var/data/2017/01
# maybe {1..31} because month can have 31 days
for day in {1..30}; do
    # check directory exist || otherwise continue with next day
    [[ -e $dir_proc/$day ]] || continue
    for file in "$dir_proc/$day/"*; do
        # check file exist      || otherwise continue with next file
        [[ -e $file ]] || continue
        # do something with "$file"
    done
done
```

EDIT with months:

```
dir_proc=/var/data/2017
for month in {01..12}; do
    for day in {01..31}; do
        # check directory exist || otherwise continue with next day
        [[ -e $dir_proc/$month/$day ]] || continue
        for file in "$dir_proc/$month/$day/"*; do
            # check file exist      || otherwise continue with next file
            [[ -e $file ]] || continue
            # do something with "$file"
        done
    done
done
```

Or shorter, with one for

```
dir_proc=/var/data/2017
for month_day in {01..12}/{01..31}; do
    # check directory exist || otherwise continue with next day
    [[ -e $dir_proc/${month_day} ]] || continue
    for file in "$dir_proc/${month_day}/"*; do
        # check file exist      || otherwise continue with next file
        [[ -e $file ]] || continue
        # do something with "$file"
    done
done
```

Comment: looks good  , if i want to have the month itself as var ? so it will be month  {1..12} ?

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `[[ -e $file ]]` test. `$file` exists as it is part of the output from `for file in "$dir_proc/$month/$day/"`. Unless of course it was deleted in the short time lapse. Even the test for month and day is somewhat redundant other than saving a few processor cycles from checking in non-existent directories for files.

Comment: @Deathgrip, this is to handle the case where there's no file: glob is not expanded and by default `file='dir/*'` maybe `shopt -s nullglob` can be used also

Comment: I always forget about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the script for all files in the directory structure, just use `find`:

```
find /var/data/2017/01 -type f -exec sh /opt/myscript.sh {} \;
```

Or with the `Processing...` lines (with GNU find):

```
find /var/data/2017/01 -type f -printf "Processing %p\n" -exec sh /opt/myscript.sh {} \;
```

If you only want to run on some subdirectories in the tree, you'll need to use `-path` or `-name` and `-prune` to limit the matches.